# How does one indicate whether a class exists in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables, pickle, nameerror

So, I am trying to make multiple savefiles for my textgame. I want to display whether a file doesn't have a `PlayerIG` class for the file.

Example (most likely won't work):

```
def TitleScreen():
    global PlayerIG
    blankHuge()
    anar()
    print('The Game of Hierarchy and Anarchy\nBy S.G. Harmonia\nText Edition\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\nPress Enter\nTo exit, type "exit".')
    StartGame = input()
    if StartGame == '':
        print('► Which file?\nTo access a file, type its number.\nTo go back, type "back".')

        Attributes = {0:PlayerIG.name,1:PlayerIG.status,2:PlayerIG.month} # raises NameError 

        print('► File 1\n',Attributes)
        if os.path.exists('TGHA1.pickle') == False:
            Attributes = 'Empty'
        blankSmall()

        print('► File 2\n',Attributes)
        if os.path.exists('TGHA2.pickle') == False:
            Attributes = 'Empty'
        blankSmall()

        print('► File 3\n',Attributes)
        if os.path.exists('TGHA3.pickle') == False:
            Attributes = 'Empty'
        blankSmall()

        print('► File 4\n',Attributes)
        if os.path.exists('TGHA4.pickle') == False:
            Attributes = 'Empty'
        blankSmall()
# more stuff...
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sinnoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\TheGameOfHierarchyAndAnarchy.py", line 786, in <module>
    TitleScreen()
  File "C:\Users\Sinnoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\TheGameOfHierarchyAndAnarchy.py", line 141, in TitleScreen
    Attributes = {0:PlayerIG.name,1:PlayerIG.status,2:PlayerIG.month}
NameError: name 'PlayerIG' is not defined
```

Is there any way I can display if a file is empty?

Comment: You have two different questions here. (1) "Is there any way I can display if a file is empty?" - Which file? You never mentioned or opened any files in your program. (2) "...whether a class exists in Python?" however, in the program, `PlayerIG` is neither a class nor a file, but a variable (probably an object). Make yourself clear.

Comment: `global PlayerIG` doesn't create a variable; it simply states that any assignment to that name should modify (or create) a global variable rather than a function local variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "whether a file doesn't have a PlayerIG class for the file"? Why would your save files have classes?